Stack Exchange's email when you sign up contains a somewhat misleading link
When you sign up for Stack Exchange, you receive an email inviting you to contribute. It invites you to "Get started with new questions that no one’s answered yet" (emphasis mine). Except the link on "new questions that no one's answered yet" actually brings you to the "No Answers" page, which often contains some quite old questions.
On Stack Overflow, for example, the first question in the list is over 7 years old, and the list includes some over 12 years old. Those questions are most certainly not new.
So, could that link either send you to new questions with no answers, or could the email call it "highly scored questions that no one's answered yet" or something in that vein?

Pretty sure that "No Answers" actually mean "No accepted or upvoted answers", the highest score is only the sort so not relevant. If anything I'd prefer to just have it removed from such an email, it's way too confusing for new users, in any form it would be sent.

@ShadowWizard actually it takes you to the “No Answers” tab of “Unanswered”. “Unanswered” is what you are describing, so I’d imagine “No Answers” is something different.

I read this a few times, and I think some words in your question are wrong. I believe you're saying that the issue is with the words "new questions", and in the last sentence of your first paragraph you mean "contains some quite old questions". The "No Answers" page is just that - questions with no answers, upvoted or otherwise. So you're either asking for one of two changes: (1) limit the scope of the page to match the text of the email and be limited to new(er) questions or (2) change the text of the email to reflect that the questions aren't necessarily new questions.

@ThomasOwens My point is this:A link from "new questions that no one's answered yet" linking to a list of questions in which the vast majority of questions are actually quite old is misleading. I am asking that it either 1.Have the link direct you to actually new questions, maybe make the link go to this or something similar or 2.Have the text in the email say "highly scored questions that no one's answered yet" or something like that.

Actually, I just checked and there's old email (from 2015) where this is the link. It's not to "No Answers" but rather "Newest", as it should be. So if you say the link is now different, it's a bug.

@ShadowWizard Yep its definetly different now.

@ShadowWizard I'd also like to note that your 2015 link is actually still no exactly, correct, as some "Unanswered" questions actually have been answered, just the answer wasn't upvoted/accepted.

Well that's true, but the bug was much "better" in the past, with only a bit misleading text. Now it's wrong even more, that's the point. :)
